I have to import data to exercise. I wrote this: EMD_df <- read_csv("Data_EMD.csv") to get it to R but receive permission denie
Error in file(con, "rb") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(con, "rb") :
cannot open file 'C:/Users/myuser/OneDrive/Documents/Data_EMD.csv': Permission denied
Thank you for helps
Sincerely
Leneve
I try to run R and Rstudio as administrator but nothing changes

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
